# How do I setup a 1:N workflow with filters in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, amqp, logstash, statsd

I'm trying to setup a single logstash worker that takes all messages from a one amqp/rabbitmq queue, filters some of the messages to send to statsD but also sends ALL the messages to elastic search. The following implementation only doesn't send ANY messages to ElasticSearch.

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "amqp-host"
    queue => "elasticsearch"
    key => "elasticsearch"
    exchange => "elasticsearch"
    type => "all"
    durable => true
    auto_delete => false
    exclusive => false
    format => "json_event"
    debug => false
  }
}

filter {
    grep {
      add_tag => "grepped"
      match => ["@message", "Execution of .*? took .* sec"]
    }

    grok {
        tags => ["grepped"]
        add_tag => "grokked"
        pattern => "Execution of %{DATA:command_name} took %{DATA:response_time} sec"
    }

    mutate {
        tags => ["grepped", "grokked"]
        lowercase => [ "command_name" ]
        add_tag => ["mutated"]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch_river {
    type => "all"
    rabbitmq_host => "amqp-host"
    debug => false
    durable => true
    persistent => true
    es_host => "es-host"
    exchange => "logstash-elasticsearch"
    exchange_type => "direct"
    index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    index_type => "%{@type}"
    queue => "logstash-elasticsearch" 
  }

 statsd {
    type => "command-filter"
    tags => ["grepped", "grokked", "mutated"]
    host => "some.domain.local"
    port => 1234
    sender => ""
    namespace => ""
    timing => ["prefix.%{command_name}.suffix", "%{response_time}"]
    increment => ["prefix.%{command_name}.suffix"]
  }
}
```

Is there some catchall filter? Or a way to arrange the tags so some messages are filtered but ALL are forwarded to ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [clone](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.11/filters/clone) filter came in handy. The following is my resulting config file.

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "amqp-host"
    queue => "elasticsearch"
    key => "elasticsearch"
    exchange => "elasticsearch"
    type => "all"
    durable => true
    auto_delete => false
    exclusive => false
    format => "json_event"
    debug => false
  }
}

filter {
    clone {
        exclude_tags => ["cloned"]
        clones => ["statsd", "elastic-search"]
        add_tag => ["cloned"]
    }

    grep {
      type => "statsd"
      add_tag => "grepped"
      match => ["@message", "Execution of .*Command took .* sec"]
    }

    grok {
        type => "statsd"
        tags => ["grepped"]
        add_tag => "grokked"
        pattern => "Execution of %{DATA:command_name}Command took %{DATA:response_time} sec"
    }

    mutate {
        type => "statsd"
        tags => ["grepped", "grokked"]
        lowercase => [ "command_name" ]
        add_tag => ["mutated"]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch_river {
    type => "all"
    rabbitmq_host => "amqp-host"
    debug => false
    durable => true
    persistent => true
    es_host => "es-host"
    exchange => "logstash-elasticsearch"
    exchange_type => "direct"
    index => "logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    index_type => "%{@type}"
    queue => "logstash-elasticsearch" 
  }

  statsd {
    type => "statsd"
    tags => ["grepped", "grokked", "mutated"]
    host => "some.host.local"
    port => 1234
    sender => ""
    namespace => ""
    timing => ["commands.%{command_name}.responsetime", "%{response_time}"]
    increment => ["commands.%{command_name}.requests"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on what the clone does here? does the order of items in the filter matter?

Comment: @FuzzyAmi It's been a while, I gave the docs a quick glance.

The "clone" filter creates new log events. However each 'cloned' event goes through the ENTIRE pipeline again. So... I clone each messages as it comes through, and add a "cloned" tag to with `add_tag => ['cloned']` then when it comes through again the `exclude_tags=>['cloned']` ensures I don't end up with an infinite loop of cloned events. 

The `clones => ['statsd', 'elastic-search']` key/value creates 2 cloned events one with each tag.

Think of it like a branching mechanism for downstream processing.

Answer (score 0):

The `clone` filter is actually unnecessary in your situation.

There are a few things I would recommend:

- Please simplify your config until you get your "base" working. Don't set optional parameters for now
- Make sure the `type` matches up
- Use tags, they are a lifesaver
- When "grepping" you should stay consistent and always use `grok` or always use `grep`. My preference is `grok`

Some other tips...
Choose what you want to do with your messages based on what **tags** they have set. Here is an example config snippet of mine:

```
grok{
   type => "company"
   pattern => ["((status:new))"]
   add_tag => ["company-vprod-status-new", "company-vprod-status-new-%{company}", "company-vprod-status-new-%{candidate_username}"]
   tags=> "company-vprod-status-change"
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    type => "company"
    index => "logstash-syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
 }
 statsd {
    host => "graphite.test.company.com"
    increment => ["vprod.statuses.new.all", "vprod.statuses.new.%{company}.all"]
    tags => ["company-vprod-status-new"]   
 }
}
```

Also, really pay close attention to your type. If you set the `type` attribute to a value that doesn't exist, then that block will never get triggered. This is why I prefer to use tags, unless there is an explicit reason for using types.

Comment: All great tips, but the answer doesn't offer an actual answer to my problem. The problem ended up being that all messages went through the grep filter and those that did not pass it were simply dropped.

Comment: It seems like there was another problem than what you just mentioned. Your ES block was configured to take all messages from the "all" type and not filter based on tags. Therefore, everything you had there was correct and what you mentioned doesn't seem like the culprit. If your solution worked, that's really great, but based on the info you provided, it didn't seem like a solution to even consider. Maybe you could edit your answer to explain why your solution worked and what it solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add:

```
drop => false
```

at the end of the grep stanza (if you are still using grep that is)